# Divs need to be in each corner of the page without overlapping?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make 4 divs in each corner of the page. I've managed to do it, but when I resize the window the divs overlap eachother, this is because the bottom divs are stuck to the bottom of the window, I just want the divs to be at the bottom of the "#wrap" div, but I'm really struggling to do it :/

In Internet Explorer all the divs are all a bit messed up as well...

Here's a live preview of it so you can see the code/page:
[enter link description here](http://henrynorthen.com/exp/simonintro/)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It's messed up (not just in IE) because (a) it's being rendered in Quirks Mode and (b) your HTML is invalid (you're closing some of your links with `<a />` instead of `</a>`, at least). Add [`<!DOCTYPE html>`](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) as the first thing in your HTML to make it render in Standards Mode and use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop users from resizing their browsers or using *ancient* resolutions.

The best you can hope for is to set a min-height/width on .wrap

Comment: Didn't work ;( and I'm just trying to put the bottom divs at the bottom of the wrap div, they don't have to always be visible and stuck at the bottom of the window.